# Jetpack Compose: Focus Styling

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am making custom components and with my custom components I am required to cover the focus state.

At the top of my component hierarchy I am tracking focus with this.

```
    val focused = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val focusModifier = modifier.onFocusEvent {
        focused.value = it.hasFocus || it.isFocused
    }

    Component(modifier = focusModifier, focused = focused.value)
```

The component is basically this:

```
@Composable
fun Component(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    focused: Boolean = false
) {
   ...
   val colorStuff = if(focused) focusColors else otherColors
   var focusModifier = modifier
   if(focused) {
       focusModifier = modifier.border(BorderStroke(2.dp, Color.Red)).padding(16.dp)
   }
    NextComponent(
       focusModifier,
       colorStuff,
       etc
    )
}
```

If I leave the code with colorStuff and focused without the focusModifier code the focus state is done correctly and the colors for the component change appropriately. But when I add the focusModifier code and do a border and padding the focus state will trigger, but then instantly be lost. I'm assuming this is because the addition of modifier code changes the build order of the component and makes it discard focus. But that doesn't make full sense either.

I essentially need to add borders/shadows around components when they are focused so this will be something I have to do multiple times. Right now I can't get it done once. Any idea what I need to do to overcome this?

Comment: "the focus state will trigger, but then instantly be lost" is an issue I also dealt with `Focus Management` in `compose`, any composable that `lost` a focus will always report its `lost` `state` to the focus manager, when you start to focus a component, and moved to the next one, `FocusManager` will report you back two states, one component that lost the focus and one that gained, I don't know your use-case but in mine, I ended up having an object with a unique ID that has an attribute of "isFocused:Boolean" to circumvent these `onFocusEvent{...}` reports.

Comment: Are you using a TextField?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti this specific case is a button component, but many of the components I have to work with have a similar design.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your question, but I'll share my use-case, maybe it could help. Consider the codes below

```
data class PersonItem(
   val id : Int,
   val isActive: Boolean = false
)
```

List Item

```
@Composable
fun PersonInfoItem() {
Column {

    // First Name
    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier.onFocusEvent {
               // report to view model this personItem received focus events
        },
        value = "",
        onValueChange = {

        }
    )

    // Last Name
    TextField(
        modifier = Modifier.onFocusEvent {
              // report to view model this personItem received focus events
        },
        value = "",
        onValueChange = {

        }
    )
}
```

`VieModel`

```
class ViewModel {

val currentFocusedItem : PersonItem? = null

fun onPersonItemFocused(personItem: PersonItem) {
    
    // this is where I validate that if the personItem argument
    // is not the same with the currentFocusedPerson, if they are not then the last one is not on focus anymore (set !isActive)
    // otherwise if they are the same, we are still on the same PersonItem
}
```

Regardless of which `TextField` received or lost its focus, as long as I'm keeping track of the `Id` of the `PersonItem` being reported to the `ViewModel` I'm guaranteed that if its the same `PersonItem`, it will retain what ever state I put into it during its `Focus`  events
(say, the item will change background color when either of the `TextField` received focus, and revert back to its original background when none of the `TextField` is focused).

Another thing to consider, these kinds components (i.e `TextFields`) report multiple inactive focus events during its initial composition, and it's kind of annoying.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Composable
fun FocusableButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onClick: () -> Unit = {},
    label: String,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    requestInitialFocus: Boolean = false
) {
    var backgroundColor by remember { mutableStateOf(FocusButtonUnselectedBackground) }
    var borderColor by remember { mutableStateOf(FocusButtonSelectedBorder) }
    fun applyColors(focusState: FocusState) {
        borderColor = if (focusState.isFocused) {
            FocusButtonSelectedBorder
        } else {
            FocusButtonUnselectedBorder
        }
        backgroundColor = if (focusState.isFocused) {
            FocusButtonSelectedBackground
        } else {
            FocusButtonUnselectedBackground
        }
    }

    val newModifier = if (requestInitialFocus) {
        val focusRequester = remember { FocusRequester() }
        LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
            focusRequester.requestFocus()
        }
        modifier
            .onFocusEvent(::applyColors)
            .focusRequester(focusRequester)
            .focusable()
    } else {
        modifier
            .onFocusEvent(::applyColors)
            .focusable()
    }

    OutlinedButton(
        onClick = { onClick() },
        modifier = newModifier,
        enabled = enabled,
        border = BorderStroke(1.dp, borderColor),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(backgroundColor = backgroundColor)
    ) {
        Text(text = label)
    }
}
```